# Error when trying to use Powershell SQL Server SMO model to access table in a specific schema

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to user PowerShell SQL Server SMO object model to access a table in a **particular database schema** (because in my database I have tables by the same name in different schemas). Here is my simplified script:

```
# Input parameters
$ServerName = "MyServer"
$DatabaseName = "MyDatabase"
$SchemaName = "dbo"
$TableName = "MyTable"

# Load the SMO assembly (SQL Server Management Objects)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")

$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $ServerName
$database = $server.Databases[$DatabaseName]
$schema = $database.Schemas[$SchemaName]
$table = $schema.Tables[$TableName]

Write-Host "Completed"
```

The script errors out on the line where I try to get schema:
`$schema = $database.Schemas[$SchemaName]`

The error says:

> Cannot index into a null array

So apparently the "Schemas" collection is somehow invalid. I even tried to ask ChatGPT to generate a similar script and it did generate the code with `$database.Schemas[$SchemaName]`. I guess it's not ready to replace humans yet :)

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong or alternative ways to get a table object in the specified database schema?

Thank you!

P.S. My PowerShell version is 5.1 and I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 or 2019.

P.P.S. When I step through the script I can see that the server connection is made:

[image]

P.P.P.S. Further research indicates that "schema" object doesn't have "Tables" collection:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's actually connecting to `MyServer`. Have you tried using an alternate `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` constructor that takes a `ServerConnection` object so that you can specify connection authentication details? Especially if the server requires username+password style SQL Logon authentication.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I believe this is exactly what I am using: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server. Also I tried stepping through my script and when I hover over the $server variable it shows correct information, so I believe it connects successfully. I will add a screenshot to my question.

Comment: and what does the `$database` object look like? Do you have access to the schema?

Comment: Same class, different constructor... [REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server#constructors). So what do you see if you `$server.Databases | Format-List`? The `$server` object will have a number of initial properties set even before it connects, but `$server.Databases` will be null if it hasn't connected successfully. Another possibility... is `MyDatabase` the correct letter case? You're accessing .NET collections, so you're not going to have the luxury of PowerShell's default case-insensitivity.

Comment: The connection is not the issue. I am able to get a complete list of databases after it connect. I did some further research and found that apparently "schema" object does not have "Tables" collection, which is very strange. I attached another screenshot at the end of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. Basically, I just need to use $database.Tables collection and filter it on a desired schema/table.  Here is a sample code (using a function this time):

```
function Compare-SQLServerTables
(
    [string]$srv1, [string]$bd1, [string]$sch1, [string]$TableName1
)
{
    # Load the SMO assembly (SQL Server Management Objects)
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null

    $server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $srv1
    $database = $server.Databases[$bd1]
    $tables = $database.Tables | Where-Object { $_.Schema -eq $sch1 -and $_.Name -eq $TableName1}
    Write-Output $tables
}

# Input parameters
$ServerName = "MyServer"
$DatabaseName = "MyDatabase"
$SchemaName = "dbo"
$TableName = "MyTable"

#function call
Compare-SQLServerTables $ServerName $DatabaseName $SchemaName $TableName
```